# Volley doesn't cache post request

Tags: caching, android-volley

I fetch data from server with following method:

```
public void process(final String url){
        this.url=url;
        GsonRequest<T> request=new GsonRequest<>(url, responseType, requestData, new Response.Listener<T>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(T response) {
                //handle response here
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {                                        
                //handle error here
            }
        });
        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        request.setShouldCache(true);
        queue.add(request);
 }
```

Some of the requests fetch signficant amount of data.I'd like `Volley` to cache data in some cases.However when I do one of these heavy request and then turn network off and then repeat my request Volley throws 
`java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "...": No address associated with hostname`.
Is there something I can do to make Volley cache responses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in server code - it didn't allow caching